# Passing data from view to controller using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

Im trying to pass user input from html to the controller and I am using jquery and ajax.I have followed this tutorial  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/post-the-data-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-using-jquery-ajax.

Here is the controller code.

```
 public class JQueryController

    {
        // GET api/<controller>
        public ActionResult Index ()
        {
            return View(); 
        }


     
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult AjaxPostCall(Userinfo userdata)
        {
            Userinfo userinfo = new Userinfo
            {
                Name = userdata.Name,
                EmailAdress = userdata.EmailAdress,
                Phone = userdata.Phone

            };

            return JSON(userinfo, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Here is the code in the cshtml file

```
@{
    @Shakesphere.Controller.JQueryController.UserInfo;
    @Model.Shakesphere.ViewModels.UserDataModel


}


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function CheckInput() {

            var userInfo = new Object();
            userInfo.Name = $('name').val();
            userInfo.EmailAddress = $('email').val();
            userInfo.Phone = $('phone').val();
            if (UserInfo != null) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/JqueryAjaxCall/AjaxPostCall',
                    data: JSON.stringify(UserInfo),
                    contenttype: "application.json; charset=utf-8",
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response != null) {
                            alert("Name:" + response.Name);
                        }

                        else {
                            alert("Something went wrong ")
                        }



                    },

                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }


                }

                )

            }



        }

    </script>
```

THe errors I get is that view and json don't exisit in current context.  Also I get an error  which is
Error   CS0117  'JQueryController' does not contain a definition for 'UserInfo' .

Comment: Your controller name does not match with ajax post request url. You must use `url: '/Jquery/AjaxPostCall',`  instead of using `url: '/JqueryAjaxCall/AjaxPostCall',` And also it must be `public class JQueryController: Controller` .

Comment: @ Gökhan Aldanmaz                                                                                                 When I define the class as public class JqueryController: Controller I get an error message saying that controller is a  namespace used like a type error CS0118

Comment: You make wrong thing about namespaces. Maybe there is a same class name with namespace name. You can check your namespace and class names.

Comment: I have renamed my namespace and no the jquery controller class can now access the controller class

Answer (score 0):

Your `JQueryController` class needs to inherit from the base `Controller` class. Change your class declaration to this:

```
public class JQueryController : Controller
```

As for the `Userinfo` issue, my guess is that you're missing a `using` statement on top of your class. Look at your `Userinfo` class, and you'll see something like:

```
namespace Foo.Bar
```

You'll need to add something along the lines of `using Foo.Bar` on top of your `JQueryController` class.